# PostgresQL to_timestamp error: invalid "MM" in source string

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

[image]

I have this table `our_table` in PostgreSQL, and I am attempting to convert this `value` column, which is a string, into a timestamp with `to_timestamp`. The 10 rows showing in the screenshot are all 10 rows of this table. I have the query:

```
select
    *,
    case when value like 'AM' then  to_timestamp(value, 'MM/DD/YYYY-HH:MI AM') else to_timestamp(value, 'MM/DD/YYYY-HH:MI PM') end as tmp
from our_table
```

...and I receive the error `ERROR: invalid value for "MM" in source string`. I noticed that `value` was type varchar(6000), and I attempted to convert it into varchar(2048) before using `to_timestamp` however this did not help.

How can I turn this string column into timestamp using to_timestamp? I have checked thoroughly and the first two digits are always, 01, 02, 03, ..., 11, or 12, with no other values, so it is odd that I receive the error I am getting. I'm not sure if this is a `type` issue or something else then. Appreciate any help!

Comment: I suspect you want HH12, since the hours aren't zero-padded.  And you shouldn't need your CASE statement; the string `AM` will match either AM or PM.  Give that, I see no reason for the error.  Perhaps you should try `LIMIT 1`, `LIMIT 2`, etc to see where it stalls.

Comment: There is no such error message in the PostgreSQL source code. What are you using?